# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class in php loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

How do i loop through the object bank to get the amount of the specified id?

`

```
<?php

$user_id = 2;

$banks_data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'amount' => '22000', 'name' => 'ken'],
    ['id' => 2, 'amount' => '24000', 'name' => 'ken'],
    ['id' => 3, 'amount' => '26000', 'name' => 'ken'],
];

foreach($banks_data as $item){
    $balance = $item['amount']::where(id, $user_id);
    
return $balance;
}
?>
```

`
suppose the user_id is 3 i want the returned figure to be 26000

Comment: You code is not valid, amount is a string you can't call it like that, balance can be found at `$item['balance']` like you do for amount.

Comment: Err, bank_data is an array of arrays, so what is an object bank?

Comment: I thought over and found a  even more PHP-way one-liner. See my answer update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a custom search method for that.

```
$banks_data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'amount' => '22000', 'name' => 'ken'],
    ['id' => 2, 'amount' => '24000', 'name' => 'ken'],
    ['id' => 3, 'amount' => '26000', 'name' => 'ken'],
];

$getBalance = function (array $data, int $userId): int {
    foreach ($data as $bank) {
        if ($bank['id'] === $userId) {
            return (int) $bank['amount'];
        }
    }
    throw new Exception('User not found');
};

echo $getBalance($banks_data, 2);
```

or a even more PHP-way one-liner

```
echo false !== ($index = array_search(2, array_column($banks_data, 'id'))) ? $banks_data[$index]['amount'] : 'not found';
```

#### Output

```
24000
```